# Playing a Spotify Playlist

Tags: python, json, spotify

I am trying to play a specified playlist using Python.  Below is my code - when I run it I get `error 400 - malformed json`.  I have run it in the online console and it works.  I have retrieved playlists, tracks, currently playing all successfully but can't get this to work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
spotifyurl = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play"
spotifyheader = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + spotifykey}
spotifydata = {'context_uri': 'spotify:user:bkmar1192:playlist:1o9HJhrKzdpDfSlOmr6bT5'}
response = requests.put(spotifyurl, headers=spotifyheader, data=spotifydata)
```

Comment: `spotifydata` is a Python dictionary. You need to pass a JSON formatted _string_ as the `data=` argument—so you'll need to convert the dictionary to JSON format first. This could be done with something like `json_string = json.dumps(spotifydata)`.

Comment: That was it thank you.